# Routing: How to allow Path parameters and Query parameters at the same time?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, attributerouting

For my ASP.NET Core 6.0 MVC web application, I need both:

```
http://example.com/users/7 and
http://example.com/users?userid=7
```

My current controller looks like this:

```
    [HttpGet("users/{userId}")]
    public IActionResult GetUser(int userId)
    { ... }
```

The first call works, the second returns a 404.

I wonder why... and what do I need to do to fix this (allow both calls)?

Comment: What happens if you try to use `http://example.com/users?userId=7`  (capitalized "I" in the "userId" name for query string parameter)

Comment: Hey marc_s. Does not make a difference. I tried this already. As far as I know this is case insensitive - at least on IIS (and I run my app on a Windows server in IIS).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

userId section is required so the second Url returned 404

You could try add ? to set Userid section nullable as below:

```
 [Route("Users/{UserId?}")]
            public IActionResult GetUser(int UserId)
            {
                return Ok();
            }
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Works for me. And super video :) +Thank you Ruikai!!